# Stream video or sound without file extension in URL in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, video, swift2, avplayer

I am trying to stream video or sound from the internet with AVPlayer but the files stored on server are just hashes and they are stored without the file extension so if I am trying to open stream like http://example.com/fileHash it wont play and the AVPlayer crosses the Play button, but when the url is with file extension like http://example.com/fileName.mp4 it works well.

I am on iOS and using latest Swift syntax, the stream I want to play with AVPlayerViewController so I am just passing the URL to the view from prepareForSegue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showVideoPlayerVC" {
        print(sender as! NSURL)
        //print http://example.com/fileHash
        let destVc = segue.destinationViewController as! AVPlayerViewController
        destVc.player = AVPlayer(URL: sender as! NSURL)
    }
}
```

Comment: The client doesn't look at the extension. it looks at the Content-Type HTTP header. You need to fix the server to sent the correct mime.

Comment: @szatmary I have exactly the same issue as OP and my server is returning content type correctly video/mp4 and it still does not play without the file extension. Any ideas?

Comment: @AIWeird how did you solve this issue. I am on RN but eager to know your approach! :(

Comment: Are there any solution ?